# No module named jsoneditor error in django app

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

Here's the error:

```
    /app$ python3 manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jsoneditor'
```

But actually I  have jsoneditor installed

```
pip3 install django-jsoneditor
Requirement already satisfied: django-jsoneditor in/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from django-jsoneditor)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from packaging->django-jsoneditor)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from packaging->django-jsoneditor)
```

my installed app

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'jsoneditor'
    ]
```

Then why this error?
What's wrong?

Comment: try run `python3 -c 'import jsoneditor'`

Comment: in app vr on other terminal window? @BearBrown

Comment: at the same terminal where you try to run `python3 manage.py`

Comment: @BearBrown app$ python3 -c 'import jsoneditor'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jsoneditor'

Comment: do you use virtual env?

Comment: I don't know I am on Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: how to check if I'm using virtual env or not

Comment: try install by `pip install django-jsoneditor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error occur in 2 cases,

**1) INSTALLED_APPS:**

please ensure your module was in under `Installed_Apps`,
you need to defined before use.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'jsoneditor',
)
```

**2) Virtualenv:**

if you are in virtualenv you should ensure your package was in by using,

```
pip freeze
```

if not, install it under virtualenv ,

```
source bin/activate
```

then `pip install django-jsoneditor`

if you installed globally and trying to import under virtulenv it wont work.

so try either then it should work

Comment: yes it is : INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'jsoneditor']

Comment: are you using virtual env ?

Comment: no are you uising source /bin/activate its virtual_env.. virtualenv is the python package for separating each app..  try pip freeze check in  it

Comment: pip freeze returned this: /app$ pip freeze
Django==1.11.4
django-jsonfield==1.0.1
psycopg2==2.7.3.1
pytz==2017.2
uWSGI==2.0.15

Comment: you had an answer. you dont have django-jsoneditor so install and try pip freeze again

Comment: pip3 install django-jsoneditor
Requirement already satisfied: django-jsoneditor in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from django-jsoneditor)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from packaging->django-jsoneditor)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from packaging->django-jsoneditor)

Comment: if you are in virtualenv move on to it. but your pip freeze says you dont have  jsoneditor so install it ... move on to specific path and install.. before that pip3 uninstall django-jsoneditor